# String (with spaces) to DOM in Java

Tags: java, xml, string, dom, xpath

I have a function which converts a string to DOM, and then uses javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory on the DOM object to pull data.

The XPathFactory works fine for the following string

`<root><test><name>A</name></test><test><name>B</name></test></root>`

but it fails if I have spaces between tags

`<root> <test> <name>A</name> </test> <test> <name>B</name> </test></root>`

I'm using XpathFactory to ready the values "A" and "B" from the DOM.

Can anyone tell me exactly why is XpathFactory failing when the string has spaces in between tags.

Thanks 
--SD

Comment: what specifically makes you think that XPathFactory is failing? Maybe you meant to ask how to formulate a proper XPath expression?

Comment: @Rambo: Yes how to formulate a proper XPath expression (if the input xml is a string with spaces between tags and is converted to a DOM)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XPath is correct and works ok, I think that the problem is that

```
list.item(i).getChildNodes().item(0).getTextContent());
```

gets the first child node of the node matching the XPath, that in the case of the XML with the spaces is the spaces right after `<employee>`, whereas in the case of the XML without the spaces is the `<name>` element.

In other words in the case with spaces the child nodes of the first `employee` element are (one per line):

```
[spaces]
<name> . . . </name>
[spaces]
<company-no> . . . </company-no>
[spaces]
<chunk-id> . . .</chunk-id>
```

in the case without spaces they are:

```
<name> . . . </name>
<company-no> . . . </company-no>
<chunk-id> . . .</chunk-id>
```

and so in the first case the child nodes you need are 1, 3 and 5, in the second case are 0, 1 and 2.

I think you should modify this piece of code:

```
 System.out.println("Name: " +list.item(i).getChildNodes().item(0).getTextContent());
 System.out.println("Company: "+list.item(i).getChildNodes().item(1).getTextContent());
 System.out.println("Chunk: "+list.item(i).getChildNodes().item(2).getTextContent());
```

to either use other XPaths to get the name, company and chunk sub-nodes or to skip the child nodes containing spaces.

Comment: Thanks, do you know how builder.parse() works? see line 36 here http://ideone.com/y5WKx I believe that it considers spaces/tabs as xml tags and interprets them as well instead of omitting. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I don't know how `builder.parse()` work, but in general XML parsers are supposed to behave that way: generate nodes in the parsed XML also for the whitespaces - as I wrote in my answer you have to change the way you use/process the result of the XPath.

Answer (score 0):

```
/root/test/name
```

or even just

```
//name
```

optionally, directly get the child text nodes

```
//name/text()
```

Comment: I think we are on different pages, The XPath expression that I've written is correct. The problem is the spaces between tags as shown in string 2, doesn't produce the right result. While no spaces produce the required result.

Comment: sorry for not giving the code earlier. Here you go http://ideone.com/ocvA1 Note that the input String emp has spaces between tags, try omitting these and you will see that the right values are printed